# OneDrive - Multiple Accounts for Windows 10

Tags: user-accounts, windows-10, onedrive

I had a workaround for working with two OneDrive accounts using separate logins in Windows 8.1. Basically I had my work OneDrive logged in on one account, and my email logged in as the email that I logged in. I then saved the OneDrive account from the Users folder as a shortcut onto my computer. This worked because all of my work was saved under my login name in the work account for document revisions and access. This worked well as long as the work account was logged in as an active user in the background.

Since upgrading to Windows 10 this workaround does not seem to work anymore.

Does anyone have a workaround or know how to use two OneDrive accounts simultaneously using Windows 10?

Comment: The best alternative is to mount your account as a network drive.